# That time does it mean? Is it a polynomial time?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was reading an article and I saw this one: 
'under the Exponential Time Hypothesis, Split Contraction cannot be solved in time $2^{o(l^{2})}\cdot n^{O(1)}$ where $l$ is the vertex cover number of the input graph'.

And next. 'it is easy to see that Split Contraction can be solved in time $2^{O(n\log n)}$'.

Could you please tell me what are these times? What are its name?

Comment: "what are these times?" They are the running times of the procedures described. More precisely, the formulas you mention are asymptotic bounds on these times. Not all such bounds have a name that describes them precisely. I'm not sure what you want to know about these bounds.

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Discrete lizard, I would like to know about these bounds.
Because I need to know its names.

I think that 2nd time is a polynomial time. Maybe I am wrong.
I need your advice

Comment: Surely $2^{O(n\log n)}$ is not polynomial time, since it is worse than exponential (with some base).

Comment: Ok. But what time is it?

Comment: Why do you think it has a name?  Why do you care what its name is?  What are you really trying to achieve?  The question seems to be based on a faulty premise (that every running time has a name and if you just know that name, you know something useful).

Comment: I just wonder how his name is. But now I realized that this is not so simple. Now I'm interested in learning more about these times.